# Issue in executing callback and saving data to mysql db

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to authenticate using google plus api and trying to save the google user details in the callback function from google plus api but due to some reason i am unable to pass values from google plus api response to callback request.
Snippet from Router.js

```
router.get("/auth/google", passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile','email'] }));
router.get("/auth/google/callback" , passport.authenticate('google') , googleInsert);
```

Snippet from User.controller.js

```
   const {
  getGoogleUserByEmail,
  createGoogleUser,
} = require("./user.service.js");

module.exports = {
  googleInsert: (req, res) => {
    body = req.body;
    body.googleId = req.body.profile.id;
    body.firstName = req.body.profile.name.givenName;
    body.lastName = req.body.profile.name.familyName;
    body.email = req.body.profile.emails[0].value;
    body.photoUrl = req.body.profile.photos[0].value;
    //const salt = genSaltSync(10);
    //body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
    //verify if email id exists
    getGoogleUserByEmail(body.email, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      //Email id already registered and exists in db
      if (results) {
        console.log("Google Email already exists");
        return res.status(409).json({
          success: 0,
          data: "Google Email already exist",
        });
      }
      console.log(
        "Google Email id is not registered, proceed with Google User Insert"
      );
      if (!results) {
        createGoogleUser(body, (err, createResults) => {
          console.log(body);
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({
              success: 0,
              message: "Database connection error",
            });
          }
          if (createResults.affectedRows == 1) {
            console.log("inside succcess is 1");
            //Insert into UserRole Table
            createUserRole(
              createResults.insertId,
              (body.role_id = 2),
              (err, results) => {
                console.log(results);
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.status(500).json({
                    success: 0,
                    message: "DB error",
                  });
                }
                if (!err) {
                  console.log("Google User created successfully");
                  return res.status(200).json({
                    success: 1,
                    data: createResults,
                  });
                }
              }
            );
          }
        });
      }
    });
  },
};
```

Passport.js

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.clientID,
        clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:1111/api/users/auth/google/callback",
        //passReqToCallback: true
      },
      (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, callback) => {
        console.log("access token", accessToken);
        console.log("refresh token", refreshToken);
        console.log("profile", profile);
        console.log("callback", callback);
      }
    )
  );
```

The issue i am getting is i am not sure how to get the value from google authentication to be used in callback request and am not sure if callback is working or not. After i select the email id from google plus api client screen, it just goes into infinite loop and no data is getting inserted into db.

```
body = req.body;
        body.googleId = req.body.profile.id;
        body.firstName = req.body.profile.name.givenName;
        body.lastName = req.body.profile.name.familyName;
        body.email = req.body.profile.emails[0].value;
        body.photoUrl = req.body.profile.photos[0].value;
```

Comment: google plus api  was discontinued when google plus shut down in 2019

Comment: You need to make a call to the google people api to get that data back.

Comment: I dont think that is the issue. I am using the tutorial(https://www.sitepoint.com/spa-social-login-google-facebook/) which has source code at git. Can you please check if you are also getting the same issue or not and if you know how to fix it. https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/social-logins-spa

Comment: Sorry i cant help you with third party tutorials i suggest you contact the company that created them.  My experience is stickily with Googles official documentation.   I can tell you that the tutorial you are following was created July 12, 2017, which is prior to Google+ shutting down, have you considered that it no longer works. again a good idea would be to contact the author.